# IOS, Swift, Animation chaining, waiting main thread until chain completes

Tags: ios, animation, swift

This question has been asked at least as many times as I've searched for the answer but never to my satisfaction. I have a view with 52 subviews representing a deck of cards. The cards appear in the center of the screen, split into two stacks of cards and then merge together as a shuffled deck.

If I call `self.standardShuffle()` from `viewDidAppear()`, after instantiating the card images, it works just fine.

But if I call `self.standardShuffle()` 2 times in a row, the second call catches the first animation in flight and and the animation is ruined. There has to be a way to block the calling thread until the animation chain completes. Timers get too unwieldy and I can't put all of my code inside animation blocks (and it doesn't work, anyway.)

Anybody have the real answer? Please.

Comment: Can you post some example code showing what constraints you want to work within? I would normally use UIView.animate... functions with the BeginFromCurrentState option.

Answer (score 5):

> There has to be a way to block the calling thread

No there is not. *Never* block. *Never*.

If you think the answers you've seen are not satisfactory, you have not read them carefully. Read them and believe them. You can easily (and in many different ways) arrange to be called back *after* the first animation; *that* is the moment to begin the second animation. Or, create a single grouped animation that performs two animations in succession.

Those are your choices — your *only* choices. If you're finding that difficult to reconcile with your code, it's because you've architected your code incorrectly. Rearchitect it. *Use* the framework, don't *fight* it.